# SWFupload problems

Tags: php, apache2, swfupload

I use SWFupload for my project but I have a small problem.

When I upload a picture locally, everything works fine. But when I use it online, it stops uploading when it hits this :

`SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 120133. Total: 120133`

- [Server info](http://www.randersakvarieforening.dk/)
- [**Log**](http://pastebin.org/98726)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it fails when the file is fully uploaded, first thing you should do is to make sure you have necessary permissions to write the file to the directory.

Comment: Hvis jeg uploadere siden efterfulgt jeg har uploadet filen, er filen kommet korrekt op, problemet er den ikke vil skrive "complate" og gå til næste fil for at uploade, uploader jeg et png fil format kommer den ikke spicelt langt, jeg ved ikke lige hvad det kan være.

Vil det hjælpe hvis jeg smider kildekoden til mit upload script op? og mit Javascript op til SWF?

Comment: Its somthing worng ( http://www.randersakvarieforening.dk/SWFUpload/ ) look, i have upload a new version to debug online... but its still have a problem to upload...

Comment: Same problem when i try this http://www.randersakvarieforening.dk/PhpFileUpload/test.php its in SilverLight and not Flash in this test.

Comment: BTW, I don't know what you said in the first comment.